# En una función return se puede devolver 2 valores? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hay alguna manera para que una función return te devuelva 2 valores?

Me sería de gran ayuda, ya que estoy haciendo un programa.

Muchas gracias de ante mano,

Comment: saludos, para entender mejor tu problema debes agregar tu codigo  y asi tambien darte una posible solucion edita tu pregunta con tu codigo: "https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/249847/edit"

Comment: en python una funcion puede retorna una tupla: `def foo(): return 1,2` entonces al usarlo obtienes 2 valores:  `a, b = foo()` que es lo que deseas obtener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por supuesto, en Python las funciones retornan una tupla cuando usas varios valores:

```
def funcion():
    return 1, 2

tupla = funcion()    

print(tupla)
# (1, 2)
```

Inclusive puedes usar desempacar la tupla en variables:

```
a, b = funcion()    # a, b = (1, 2)
print(a)
# 1
print(b)
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
def miFuncion(nombre, edad):
  if int(edad)<18:
    mensaje = "te invito un helado !!"
  else:
    mensaje = "Te invito al cine"
  return nombre, mensaje

resultado = miFuncion('Fernanda', 17)
print(resultado)
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despues del **return** debes agregar lo que deseas retornar.